# GNU stow. Only symlink files, not directories

Tags: symbolic-link, gnu, dotfiles

I'd like to manage my dotfiles with a Git repository and `stow`. [Here is my current repository](https://github.com/strafe/dotfiles) that includes the files/directories I'd like to stow and a `Makefile` with the command I'm using `make stow`.

Unfortunately, I have run into an issue when stow encounters non-existant directories. For example if I delete my `~/.config/yabai/` directory (to simulate it not already existing on a new install) and run `make stow` it will symlink the entire directory:

```
$ ls -l
[...]
lrwxr-xr-x   1 adam staff   26 Mar 12 19:28 yabai -> ../.dotfiles/.config/yabai
[...]
```

This causes an issue because then if I, or the program create additional files in this directory, they will appear in my `~/.dotfiles/` directory as well.

---

This issue does not occur if the directory already exists because then the files inside it are linked instead of the directory itself:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x   3 adam staff   96 Mar 12 19:43 yabai
```

```
$ ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 adam staff  37 Mar 12 19:43 yabairc -> ../../.dotfiles/.config/yabai/yabairc
```

---

Based on the amount of people using `stow` to manage dotfiles, I imagine there is a way to workaround this behaviour. Possibly where the directory structure is recreated first and then links are created.

Comment: did you try using the `--no-folding` flag? Eg. `stow --no-folding yabai` – it should only link the ‘leaves’ without linking whole directories (which stow calls folding to make fewer symlinks)